# Rails 4 Getting Record and Count of Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have two models,

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :challenges
end
```

**challenge.rb**

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

In my view, I'm trying to do a count

**views/items/index.html.haml**

```
- @items.each do |i|
  = i.challenge.count
```

---

**challenge** has these columns:

- id
- user_id
- item_id
- description

**item** has these columns

- id
- title
- description

---

I'm getting this error

```
undefined method `challenge' for #
```

on the line

```
= i.challenge.count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `challenges` (plural noun).

```
= i.challenges.count
```

By the way, because calling SQL count every time is quite expensive, so I recommend using [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) to make finding the number of belonging objects more efficient.

Comment: The documentation for counter_cache is confusing... it uses `orders_count` and then shows `:count_of_orders`. can you explain?

Comment: `orders_count` is the default name, just set `counter_cache: true` and it should work. If you want to use another name like `count_of_orders`, you must specify this like `counter_cache: :count_of_orders`. In your case, `challenges_count` is the default name.

Comment: Got it, so I still don't need to add a new column for :challenges_count? or does setting it to true already takes care of the behind work?

Comment: You need to add `challenges_count` column to your **items** table (via migration as @Tsubasa Maeda's answer), and use `counter_cache: true` in your **Challenge** model

Answer (score 1):

Actually `= i.challenges.count` is fine.

But you should use counter_cache.

ChallengeModel

`belongs_to :item, counter_cache: item`

Migration

`add_column :items, :challenges_count, :integer, default: 0`

These codes will help to reduce useless database traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! +1 for the extra help!

Comment: Also, is it supposed to be `item` or `:item` or `:challenges_count`?